# Errors with commands (academic document)

Tags: errors, natbib, geometry, apacite

I am using Texworks for a paper, and I am having issues with some specific commands, which throw some errors when loading the packages.

First Error:

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `Optionen' undefined in families `Gm
```

And then:

```
! Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'
```

My code is:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[preprint,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[]{interact}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[capposition=top]{floatrow}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[Optionen]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{ntheorem}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%\theoremseparator{:}
%\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
%\let\citefullauthor\relax
%\let\citetext\relax
%\let\defcitealias\relax
%\let\Citealt\relax
%\let\Citealp\relax
\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-1em}#1}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\theoremseparator{:}
%\newtheorem{hyp}{Hypothesis}
%\let\citefullauthor\relax
%\let\citetext\relax
%\let\defcitealias\relax
%\let\Citealt\relax
%\let\Citealp\relax
\newcommand{\rowgroup}[1]{\hspace{-1em}#1}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%%\usepackage{commenting} only in draft mode
%%\declareauthor{hb}{Hendrik}{blue}
%%\declareauthor{gp}{XXX}{green!30!black}
%\usepackage{setspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace
%\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\singlespacing}% Single spacing in tabular environment

%\usepackage[natbibapa,nodoi]{apacite}% Citation support using apacite.sty. Commands using natbib.sty MUST be deactivated first!
%\setlength\bibhang{12pt}% To set the indentation in the list of references using apacite.sty. Commands using natbib.sty MUST be deactivated first!
%\renewcommand\bibliographytypesize{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont}% To set the list of references in 10 point font using apacite.sty. Commands using natbib.sty MUST be deactivated first
```

From my understanding, the first error arises from including (option) given that some other previous package probably uploaded the geometry package.  The second error seems to be incompatibility - but I am a bit at loss as to how to proceed, since I can't download the packages and actually start my work.

Thanks in advance,

M

Comment: Welcome! It seems like you received a preamble from a friend and it's full of packages you're likely not to need. Start by commenting out those you don't know about. In particular, `Optionen` is not a valid option for `geometry`, nor you can load both `natbib` and `biblatex`.

Comment: Indeed, thats what happened, now, and yes, I did change it to (Option) but it still did not go thru. I mean, As you say I am not particularly sure why  I need geometry so I did remove it, but then natbib/biblatex was an issue, and I was particularly sure if I needed both for my bibliography,

Comment: No, you don't need both as they're incompatible. I believe it's better if you start from a fresh preamble and add only what you really need.

Comment: Start by deleting _every_ package from that list and only add packages if you actually need them.

Comment: Also, don't load packages more than once, and load `hyperref` last (with [certain exceptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/2417)).